# android set spinner dropdown window as wide as screen

Tags: android, spinner

How can I set spinner's dropdown window as wide as screen? I mean no margin in both left and right sides.

```
<Spinner
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="60"
  android:entries="@array/entries"
  android:dropDownWidth="500dp"
></Spinner>
```

I set android:dropDownWidth to 500dp, but dropdown window still has left and right margin.

Comment: these are the properties set by the android through styles. Create a new style and overrides those.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain Do you know which style and where to override?

Comment: Override android:spinnerStyle xml item in your app or activity theme. Here is nice sample: http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/03/easily-create-a-default-custom-styled-spinner-android/